# Change user's display name programmatically

Tags: users, username

I'd like to change a user's display name using this code snippet in my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
$user_id = 672;
$display_name= 'Les Yeux';

$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $display_name ) );
```

This is adapted from this topic in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

But I can't get it to work. It didn't change anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: How are you checking the results? Are you looking at the database directly? What? And what is the point? This is value is trivial to change from the backend. Why do you need to cook up this piece of code?

Comment: @s_ha_dum    I had an issue with my site, some users don't have a display name for a reason that I ignore. The result is that their profile doesn't have a name on it (look at the name of your browser tab for example): http://ouiaremakers.com/utilisateur/672/ comparing to http://ouiaremakers.com/utilisateur/1  I'm trying to fix this by changing their display_name (which is what is supposed to appear on their profile), bc nothing works from the back office

Comment: Ok. That information helps but you did not answer the first question: How are you checking the results?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Nothing changes on these profiles ... I tried with the profile I sent you and it didn't display a name

Comment: And you are still not answering the question! ***How are you checking?*** Are you looking at the database via PHPMyAdmin or other tool? Are you just looking at the generated page? Are you using some function to check the user data? ***How?*** What is the mechanism you are using to determine that the `wp_update_user()` code doesn't work?

Comment: Well that's how I check ! I go to the profile of the user I changed the display name of, and if it doesn't display anything, it's because it didn't work ... how can I check the user data ?

Comment: Are you logged in with a user that has permission to change other users?

Comment: FWIW updating display_name like this didn't show me any results in the back end user editor... it turns out that is concatenating first_name and last_name, not using display_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pasted your code into my `functions.php` with a different ID and checked the user's page in `/wp-admin/user-edit.php` - it works, the value in `Display name publicly as` field is updated.

Most likely something is wrong with your output on the user page. Check your template file. Or, if you can't find the problem, edit the question and update it by pasting only the relevant code from your template - **not** the entire template.